# Using multiple unnamed arguments (... ellipses) in custom function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, custom-function

I am new to writing custom functions in R.

I have a dataset that has the same graph format applied to it multiple times. So instead of copying and pasting the code, and modifying for each dataset, I want to create a function.

I have multiple layers in a ggplot graph. I want to be able to use the `...` argument for most of the layers. For example, if I put the `...` as `size = 10`, it makes the line thicker, and the jitter points larger. What if I only want `size = 10` to apply to `stat_summary`, and not `geom_jitter` etc.?

Using the iris dataset this is what I have tried so far:

```
jitter_graph_mm1 <- function(data, x, y, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, ...) {
  ggplot(data, aes({{x}}, {{y}})) +
    stat_summary(fun = median, show.legend = FALSE, geom="crossbar", ...) +
    geom_jitter(show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.25, ...) +
    labs(x=xlab, y=ylab)
}

jitter_graph_mm1(data=iris, x=Species, y=Sepal.Width, ylab = "hi", size = 10)
```

Comment: You need two separate arguments. For example, `size.jitter`, and maybe change `size` to `size.stat`.

Comment: In ggplot2 v3.4.0 `linewidth` replaces `size` for lines, so these should in principle be separated already if you switch to the latest version.